# How to choose the ABI architecture for iOS app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, mobile-application

I am developing iOS app using Xamarin Forms and I have trouble in choosing the ABI architecture for iOS app. We are targeting iPhones and iPads with iOS version 9 and above.

After the lots of googling, I got the below,

https://www.innerfence.com/howto/apple-ios-devices-dates-versions-instruction-sets

http://wanderingcoder.net/2010/07/19/ought-arm/

My questions are below,

We have three types of architectures,

- ARMv7
- ARMv7s
- ARM64

Which architecture or architecture combination will cover the widest range of devices released after 2010?

Will the iOS app build with ARMv7 work in iOS devices having ARMv7s architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the answer to your question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21422550/1771254).

Part of this information can also be found when choosing the architecture in Xamarin Studio.

[image]

> Which architecture or architecture combination will cover the widest range of devices released after 2010?

ARMv7 + ARM64

Which is the default in Xamarin.Forms Apps. Of course this is taking into consideration the app size because nothing stop you of using: ARMv7 + ARMv7s + ARM64 but your final application will be bigger in size.

> Will the iOS app build with ARMv7 work in iOS devices having ARMv7s architecture?

Yes it does. Bellow is the compatibility table (an old one to show ARMv7s devices) a more updated can be seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html)

[image]

As you can see ARMv7 builds runs even over iPhone 6

Hopes this helps!